# Regex to filter all the inner bracketed expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm

I'm building a query builder interface in which the expression has to be validated for ambiguity. I need a correct regex syntax for the following example expressions. The criteria is, at a certain level (i.e., with a set of brackets), both `+` and `-` cannot be present. For example `(A + B + C)` is right were as `(A + B - C)` is wrong. I validated it by checking if both `+` & `-` are present. I'm not sure how to do this correctly if there is more than one level.

```
For ex: (A + (B - C - D) - E)
```

Here, though `(B - C - D)` is not ambiguous but on the whole it is. I'm planning to solve it by replacing all the inner brackets with a character `X` which will look like: `(A + X - E)` and then verify if it has more than both `+` and `-` symbols in it. I used regex `\((.*?)\)` to select the elements between `(` & `)` and it filtered `(A + (B - C - D)` instead of `(B - C - D)`. How should I modify my regex to avoid this problem. Also it should work for the following cases too.

```
(A + H + (B + (C + D - E)) = (A + H + X)
(A + H + (B + (C + D - E) - F) - (G + H - I)) = (A + H + X - X)
```

If there is a better approach compared to the above, I'm happy to use that as well.

Comment: You are better off writing a custom parser for that...

Comment: You want to replace all `\(([^()]*)\)` in a loop until no match is found, right?

Comment: Check [this code](http://ideone.com/Jvqi5v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select with `/\([^()]*\)/` evaluate the signs, then replace this inner parenthesis with a dummy value. Repeat this until there is no result from the regex. You should use without global option `g`; thus will only select the first occurrence.

This is assuming given math formula is always correct, you might want to add extra control such as there is no case with `(A + () + B)`. If there won't be such cases, the first small logic will help.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but for "(A + H + (B + (C + D - E) - F) - (G + H - I))" it outputs "A + H + (B + X - F) - X" instead of "A + H + X - X". Can this be fixed directly or should I add a loop as your said?

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression will probably suffice for your needs:

```
"\\([^\\(\\)]*\\)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but for "(A + H + (B + (C + D - E) - F) - (G + H - I))" it outputs "A + H + (B + X - F) - X" instead of "A + H + X - X". Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [grappa](https://github.com/fge/grappa). Simple enough. Of course, it requires that you can use it in your project, it's no small jar.

Note that the main will generate a zip file with all the events; you can open this zip with [the debugger](https://github.com/fge/grappa-debugger) to see what is going on during parsing :)

```
public class CustomParser
    extends BaseParser<Object>
{
    public Rule spaces()
    {
        return zeroOrMore(wsp());
    }

    public Rule var()
    {
        return charRange('A', 'Z');
    }

    @Cached
    public Rule parenContents(final char operator)
    {
        return join(firstOf(var(), expression()))
            .using(sequence(spaces(), ch(operator), spaces()))
            .min(2);
    }

    public Rule plus()
    {
        return parenContents('+');
    }

    public Rule minus()
    {
        return parenContents('-');
    }

    public Rule expression()
    {
        return sequence(
            '(',
            spaces(),
            firstOf(plus(), minus()),
            spaces(),
            ')'
        );
    }

    public Rule input()
    {
        return sequence(
            expression(),
            spaces(),
            '=',
            spaces(),
            expression(),
            EOI
        );
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final Path zip = Paths.get("/tmp/t.zip");


        final List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(
            "(A + B + (C - D)) = (A - C - E)",
            "(A + H + (B + (C + D - E)) = (A + H + X)",
            "(A + H + (B + (C + D - E) - F) - (G + H - I)) = (A + H + X - X)"
        );


        for (final String input: inputs) {
            final CustomParser parser = Grappa.createParser(CustomParser.class);

            final ListeningParseRunner<Object> runner
                = new ListeningParseRunner<>(parser.input());

            final TracingListener<Object> listener
                = new TracingListener<>(zip, true);

            runner.registerListener(listener);
            System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", input, runner.run(input).isSuccess());
        }
    }
}
```